# One SAN connecting to Hyper-V and VMware

Tags: hyper-v, storage, storage-area-network

my customer currently has two hypervisor types in place - using VMware for Linux systems and Hyper-V for Windows.  They currently have different storage infra for each of these platforms which cost them quite a bit to maintain and support.  Therefore we're thinking to consolidate the underlying infrastructure to support both platforms.

Some questions:

- Should we opt to buy a SAN for the two platforms - can we map the same SAN infra, but different LUNs to VMware and Hyper-v hosts? (assume that they are compatible with both hypervisors)
- Would you recommend to also look at consolidating the hypervisors - to either VMware or Hyper-V to make the process a lot simpler - not to mention may reduce support costs too.
- If you recommend to consolidate both server and storage - which one would you think make sense to start first with.

Cheers.

Comment: You don't need a SAN for each hypervisor. Arguably you don't need a SAN at all. One way to reduce TCO is by reducing complexity  `2 hypervisors > 1 hypervisor`. VMware for Linux sounds relatively expensive for what if offers compared to KVM, et al. But VtC as primarily opinion based.

Comment: It depends... do you have any details on workload or the existing equipment at the customer's site?

Comment: True, you don't need a SAN, but assuming that you the customers already have them now and we can either renew or repurpose the SAN with a view of consolidating them. Agree that this is not an ideal scenario of having multiple hypervisors.  Hence my questions.

Comment: It's NetApp based - FAS 3210

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to have separate storage for each hypervisor. Storage is designed to simultaneously serve data to many different types of clients. You want to make sure it's properly sized to do the job, of course.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I would thought so.  Any thoughts on servers (hypervisors) consolidation?

Comment: Nope, not something I have experience with.